# Google data view filtering

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to make a website that will let users input how they want to filter the Google Visualization data view. I have everything working except the input. The user enters how they want to filter the data into a HTML input box and the JavaScript takes the input and evaluates the string as code using

```
new Function(input)
```

input is the variable that contains the string that the user entered.

ex.

```
view.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, minValue: new Date(2007, 0, 1)}])
```

This function is placed into the setRows method. And that is where it breaks because for some reason, the evaluated string returns undefined.
Example of what my code looks like:

```
function filter(t) {
    //instantiate data view
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    // if query not empty, pass into 'new Function()' and then into 'setRows'
    // if I don't add "view" argument, it tells me that view is undefined if you have it in the query like the example
    if (t.rowQuery.value) {
        var rowQuery = new Function("view", t.rowQuery.value.split('/'));
        view.setRows(rowQuery(view));
    }

    // draw data view
    chart.draw(view, {allowHtml: true, showRowNumber: true});
}
```

I originally wanted to use Google's query, but I couldn't get it to work for any other source except Google spreadsheet.